# More information on function like variables?

Tags: c++, function, variables

While I was reading an article on rvalues I stumbled across a piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    int& foo();
}
```

and I'm not quite sure what the parenthesis in `foo()` mean in terms of what this is defining or what how this is used. I'm assuming is has something to do with functions, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a declaration of the function `foo` that takes no parameters and returns a reference to an integer.

Comment: I didn't know you could declare functions inside the body of another function. Neat.

Answer (score 1):

It is declaring a function at the scope of another function.

Comment: I'm a C# programmer so this looked completely foreign to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a local declaration for a function that will be defined later. It is local and can be used locally.